# Create a bash alias for the cd - command

Tags: bash, alias

I'd like the create the alias `--` for the bash `cd -` command. Searching to solve this problem, I found the advice to use this alias:

```
alias -- -="cd -"
```

However, that leads to the following error, as seen in this session snippet:

```
chris@DeathStar:~$ cd .vim
chris@DeathStar:~/.vim$ --
-bash: --: command not found
chris@DeathStar:~/.vim$
```

My `bash --version`:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.39(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.2.1)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not an extra, but as you can see below I needed another!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother with aliases.  Use a function instead:

```
--() { cd -; }
```

Comment: Is it better not to use an alias (now that it is working using the answer provided by @Costi) for some reason?

Comment: Aliases are far less flexible (eg, you can't pass arguments), offer no advantages over functions, and are more prone to error.  I recommend avoiding them.

Comment: @Costi `ls(){ command ls -G; }` and `grep() { command grep --color; }`

Comment: I realized it's not that painful myself and deleted the malicious answer. However, to fully simulate the alias you need to pass the extra arguments as `"$@"`, but that's still not painful enough. So I give up and vote for your answer :)

Comment: As seen in `man bash`: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."

Answer (score 7):

The alias you created seems to be `-`, not `--`. If you want it to be `--`, you need to declare it as:

```
alias -- --="cd -"
```

You can always check the list of declared aliases in your shell session, by simply typing `alias`.

P.S.

The first `--` sequence following the `alias` has nothing to do with the alias name, it's just needed in order for the `alias` command to not consider following parameters starting with a `-` as command options.